# DATE_ADD only add business days?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, dateadd

How would I calculate the following skipping the weekend and only including business days?

```
DATE_ADD(A.PO_SENT_DATE, INTERVAL C.DELIVERY_BUS_DAYS DAY) AS PROMISE_DATE
```

An example of the data would look as follows, where DELV_DATE is the order_date plus DELV_BUS_DAYS only adding business days

```
+------------+-------------+-----------------+
| order_date | DELV_BUS_DAYS |    DELV_DATE   |
+------------+-------------+----------------- +
| 08/08/19   | 16           |       xxxx     |
| 08/08/19   | 16           |       xxxx     |
+------------+-------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30877.t-sql-extending-dateadd-function-to-skip-weekend-days.aspx

Comment: tsql or bigquery?!

Comment: bigquery, sorry unsure of the difference

Answer (score 1):

This should get you it in BQ:

```
SELECT
  DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL (17 + DATE_DIFF('2021-09-03',CURRENT_DATE(),WEEK(SATURDAY)) + DATE_DIFF('2021-09-03',CURRENT_DATE(),WEEK(SUNDAY))) DAY)
```

Hope this helps :)